# MYSQL - Is there a better way to query multiple unique values than using a large statement containing "OR"s

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple MySQL query that looks something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (id = 1173)
OR (id = 223)
OR (id = 363443)
OR (id = 11532)
OR (id = 45663)
OR (id = 28313)
OR (id = 717713)
OR (id = 128313)
```

And so on with about 10-100 ORs per query.

I'm just wondering if there's a more efficient or cleaner way of performing this query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You can use `IN`, like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1173,223,363443,11532,45663,28313,717713,128313)
```